# Adding Padding To The 'left' of a Text Field

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a text field with a background but to make it look right the text field needs to have some padding on the left side of it a bit like the NSSearchField does. How would I give the text field some padding on the **left**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a custom NSTextFieldCell that overrides [drawingRectForBounds:](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCell/drawingRectForBounds:). Have it inset the rectangle by however much you want, then pass than new rectangle to [super drawingRectForBounds:] to get the normal padding, and return the result of that call.

Comment: I see, What would I put in the method to define how much I want it to be inset or is there some example code of this?

Comment: Thanks for that link, Would I use this function  "NSRect NSMakeRect(float x, float y, float w, float h)" inside the method and change the x,y,w and h to make it inset?

Answer (score 9):

smorgan's answer points us in the right direction, but it took me quite a while to figure out how to restore the customized textfield's ability to display a background color -- you must call `setBorder:YES` on the custom cell.

This is too late to help Joshua, but here's the how you implement the customized cell:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
// subclass NSTextFieldCell
@interface InstructionsTextFieldCell : NSTextFieldCell {        
}
@end

#import "InstructionsTextFieldCell.h"

@implementation InstructionsTextFieldCell

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here. (None needed.)
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSRect)drawingRectForBounds:(NSRect)rect {

    // This gives pretty generous margins, suitable for a large font size.
    // If you're using the default font size, it would probably be better to cut the inset values in half.
    // You could also propertize a CGFloat from which to derive the inset values, and set it per the font size used at any given time.
    NSRect rectInset = NSMakeRect(rect.origin.x + 10.0f, rect.origin.y + 10.0f, rect.size.width - 20.0f, rect.size.height - 20.0f);
    return [super drawingRectForBounds:rectInset];

}

// Required methods
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    return [super initWithCoder:decoder];
}
- (id)initImageCell:(NSImage *)image {
    return [super initImageCell:image];
}
- (id)initTextCell:(NSString *)string {
    return [super initTextCell:string];
}
@end
```

(If, like Joshua, you only want an inset at the left, leave the origin.y and height as is, and add the same amount to the width -- not double -- as you do to the origin.x.)

Assign the customized cell like this, in the awakeFromNib method of the window/view controller that owns the textfield:

```
// Assign the textfield a customized cell, inset so that text doesn't run all the way to the edge.
InstructionsTextFieldCell *newCell = [[InstructionsTextFieldCell alloc] init];
[newCell setBordered:YES]; // so background color shows up
[newCell setBezeled:YES];
[self.tfSyncInstructions setCell:newCell];
[newCell release];
```

Comment: This works great for my NSTokenField with a button! Just remember to setBorder:YES and any other properties you would set on the field itself.