# OSX NSTextField with layer background color not working

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, appkit

I have the following subclass of `NSTextField` (with corresponding subclass of `NSTextFieldCell` for spacing [approach found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9027461/895453)]).  I'm trying to change the border color and background color on "focus", but it isn't working.

```
class TGTextField: NSTextField {
    override func viewWillDraw() {
        self.layer?.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer?.cornerRadius = 2
        self.textColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: 55/255, green: 54/255, blue: 54/255, alpha: 1)
        self.focusRingType = .None
        self.font = NSFont(name: "ProximaNova-Medium", size: 16)!

        setBlurredStyles()
    }

    private func setFocusedStyles() {
        self.layer?.borderColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: 92/255, green: 188/255, blue: 214/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: 247/255, green: 252/255, blue: 252/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
    }

    private func setBlurredStyles() {
        self.layer?.borderColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: 221/255, green: 221/255, blue: 221/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    }

    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        if super.becomeFirstResponder() {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.setFocusedStyles()
            })
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        if super.resignFirstResponder() {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.setBlurredStyles()
            })
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

class TGTextFieldCell: NSTextFieldCell {
    override init(imageCell image: NSImage?) {
        super.init(imageCell: image)
    }

    override init(textCell aString: String) {
        super.init(textCell: aString)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawingRectForBounds(theRect: NSRect) -> NSRect {
        let rectInset = NSMakeRect(theRect.origin.x + 7, theRect.origin.y + 7, theRect.size.width, theRect.size.height)
        return super.drawingRectForBounds(rectInset)
    }
}
```

In fact, it appears that trying to set `self.layer?.backgroundColor` to anything anywhere doesn't work.  I can't just set `backgroundColor` on the textfield itself, because based on the cell, the background color is offset.

How can I set the `backgroundColor` on the layer of an `NSTextField` subclass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a simple problem... but requires a lot of hacky code. I have some working snippet for you.

Make sure your text fields are layer backed!

Get rid of all that custom stuff in the cell. Apple want to retire them soon... Not even sure any valid cases operate with cells:

```
class TGTextFieldCell: NSTextFieldCell {

}
```

Next we get to the actual:

```
class TGTextField: NSTextField
```

Define a property holding focused state:

```
private var isFocused = false
```

Override becoming first responder as you did originally:

```
override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    if super.becomeFirstResponder() {
        isFocused = true
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, we cannot capture the moment of blur easily. There are some long explanations for that in internet... but we will capture blur in a the event subscription:

```
    func subscribeForEndEdit(){
    self.drawsBackground = false
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"didEndEdit:", name: NSControlTextDidEndEditingNotification, object: nil)
}

func didEndEdit(notification: NSNotification){
    isFocused = false
}
```

Now call that subscription in the constructors overrides:

```
override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frameRect)

    subscribeForEndEdit()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)

    subscribeForEndEdit()
}
```

Now prevent background drawing:

```
    self.drawsBackground = false
```

The final piece is changing background on drawing:

```
override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    //Draw cell content here
    super.cell?.drawInteriorWithFrame(dirtyRect, inView: self)

    if isFocused {

        self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor().CGColor
    } else {

        self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    }


}
```

The entire file is:

```
import Cocoa

class TGTextField: NSTextField {

private var isFocused = false

override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frameRect)

    subscribeForEndEdit()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)

    subscribeForEndEdit()
}

  func subscribeForEndEdit(){
    self.drawsBackground = false
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"didEndEdit:", name: NSControlTextDidEndEditingNotification, object: nil)
}

func didEndEdit(notification: NSNotification){
    isFocused = false
}


override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    //Draw cell content here
    super.cell?.drawInteriorWithFrame(dirtyRect, inView: self)

    if isFocused {

        self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor().CGColor
    } else {

        self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    }


}

override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    if super.becomeFirstResponder() {
        isFocused = true
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

}

class TGTextFieldCell: NSTextFieldCell {

}
```

Here is the picture of what I get:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response!  I can't, however, get rid of the cell, unless I can reproduce the way of getting padding inside of the text field like I did with my cell subclass.  If you can point me to a way of doing that, I'll certainly ditch the cell (and accept your answer :) ).

Comment: I said to get rid of cell for just that specific background business. You can keep your cell for sure. I just pasted all your code and it worked. `class TGTextFieldCell: NSTextFieldCell {

    override func drawingRectForBounds(theRect: NSRect) -> NSRect {
        let rectInset = NSMakeRect(theRect.origin.x + 7, theRect.origin.y + 7, theRect.size.width, theRect.size.height)
        return super.drawingRectForBounds(rectInset)
    }
}` Try yourself. You may need to alter actual numbers though. Padding looks going a bit deeper than needed.

Comment: Ok!  This worked great, I just needed to override `becomeFirstResponder` like I did and call `super.becomeFirstResponder` to wrap setting the variable and returning true (is this perhaps called even when it's not becoming the first responder)?  Is there a reason I shouldn't do that, or can I edit your answer to include that bit?

Comment: You can try to override becomeFirstResponder, but I see no reason in that jump from queue. It just does not make sense to me. It looks like a Javascript approach where you get off main loop to postpone actions... but I am not sure it work the same way in Apple world... If you just capture super.becomeFirstResponder() in some variable then yes, but as I said earlier, this always returns true until you have explicit logic to prevent user from getting in/out. If you do have such logic, so yes perhaps original code makes sense (without jumping queue though). But then it has no relation to backgrou

Comment: Yeah, I'm not actually getting the main queue anymore, just checking to see if `super.becomeFirstResponder` returns true before setting the var and returning true.  I was playing with it before and it wasn't updating the UI, and I remember reading somewhere that you should always update the UI on the main queue, so I tried it and it fixed it.  However, I'm not using it anymore and it's working fine.

Answer (score -3):

try to put your set background color code in `viewWillDraw`. For example:

```
-(void)viewWillDraw {
    [super setBackgroundColor:[NSColor yellowColor]];
}
```

Comment: I can't just `setBackgroundColor`, because based on the cell, the background color is offset.

Comment: Also the method for setting the background color is happening in `viewWillDraw`, it's just calling a method to do it (`setBlurredStyles`)