# NSTextField Padding on the Left

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, nstextfield

How do you add padding to the left of the text in a text field cell using swift? Previous answers are only for UITextField or in Objective C. To be clear, this is for an NSTextField.

Comment: An NSTextField doesn't seem to have the same member functions as a UITextField.

Comment: @NSNoob Because it's for OS X?

Comment: @Desdenova Exactly. I'm developing an app for macOS. Sure wish there was more similarity between it and iOS development!

Comment: @Desdenova , pbodks, Just saw the OSX tag. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9027461/4063602) is an example of someone who has made a custom `NSTextFieldCell` in Objective C.

Ported to Swift that looks like this:

```
import Cocoa

class PaddedTextFieldCell: NSTextFieldCell {

    @IBInspectable var leftPadding: CGFloat = 10.0

    override func drawingRect(forBounds rect: NSRect) -> NSRect {
        let rectInset = NSMakeRect(rect.origin.x + leftPadding, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width - leftPadding, rect.size.height)
        return super.drawingRect(forBounds: rectInset)
    }
}
```

I've added the padding as a `@IBInspectable` property. That way you can set it as you like in Interface Builder.

### Use With Interface Builder

To use your new `PaddedTextFieldCell` you drag a regular `Text Field` to your xib file

[image: Normal Text Field Cell]

and then change the class of the inner `TextFieldCell` to be `PaddedTextFieldCell`

[image: Change TextFieldCell to PaddedTextFieldCell]

Success!

[image: The final result]

### Use From Code

To use the `PaddedTextFieldCell` from code, you *could* do something like this (thank you to @Sentry.co for assistance):

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField! {
        didSet {
            let paddedTextField = PaddedTextFieldCell()
            paddedTextField.leftPadding = 40
            textField.cell = paddedTextField
            textField.isBordered = true
            textField.isEditable = true
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: This only works if there is no background colour set or the border is not customised. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870474/osx-nstextfield-with-layer-background-color-not-working

Comment: wtf? Answer is about `NSTextField`, not about `NSTextFieldCell`. I still cannot figure out how to add padding to `NSTextField` (not `NSTextFieldCell`)

Comment: @fnc12: Every `NSTextField` has a `NSTextFieldCell`, and that is implementing the drawing. So if you want to customize drawing of a text field, you need to tweak its cell or implement your own `NSTextFieldCell` and assign it to the text field.

Comment: Please add instructions regardign how to implement the cell in the text field. thanks

Comment: @Sentry.co sorry, I'm not sure I follow your question, could you elaborate please :)  I have the `PaddedTextField` which inherits from NSTextFieldCell` (so...it should probably be named `PaddedTextFieldCell` I can see now... 5 years later :)). That is the implementation of `NSTextFieldCell` and that is used _inside_ the `NSTextField` to handle drawing of the text field with padding. Don't know if that answers your question or I managed to confuse you :)

Comment: Seems you can do `NSTextField().cell = NSTextFieldCell()` to set a cell to a textfield. Thanks

Comment: Ah! Cool, I learned something as well then. I'll update my answer to reflect that as well...and rename from `PaddedTextField` to `PaddedTextFieldCell` to make it clearer what we're looking at here :) Thanks